# Measuring total number of active (HTTP) connections with Metrics in Dropwizard application

Tags: dropwizard, metrics, codahale-metrics

I have a Dropwizard application I am working with where I need to be able to monitor for active HTTP connections.  I know Metrics provides classes for Instrumenting Jetty, and of interest to me is measuring total number of active connections....however the javadoc doesn't help me much, and I can't find any examples of how this specific functionality is implemented.  Does anyone have any examples they can share?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact use-case is but if you just need to be able to see active connections I think the simplest solutions are just using monitoring solutions like JMX, Datadog, New Relic, or Appdynamics. If you need it in the code I think you'd need to manually implement something. I'd recommend StatsD or Redis is that's the path you go down.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this.....I am implementing server sent events using SseBroadcaster.  The way I have my code implemented is such that I am always broadcasting events on certain event changes, and I would like to limit this to times when there are only active HTTP request.  I will check out StatsD and Redis.